# Doing prepend with count++

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to turn headings like this:

```
Greetings

Introductions

Numbers

(etc.)
```

into this:

```
1. Greetings

2. Introductions

3. Numbers

(etc.)
```

So I wrote this:

```
  var outlineCount = 0
  $('.page-template-page-outline .entry-content > h2').prepend('<span class="lesson-number">' + outlineCount++ + '.</span> ')
```

But what I'm getting instead is this:

```
0. Greetings

0. Introductions

0. Numbers

(etc.)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The string is evaluated and outlineCount is equal to 0; that string then gets prepended to each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looping over each element and then prepend the content. What you're instead doing is applying it to *all the elements in the jQuery collection*.

So, it will be `0` as the value of `outlineCount` will only be `1` after the `++` postfix operator.

```
$('.page-template-page-outline .entry-content > h2').each(function(i) {
   $(this).prepend('<span class="lesson-number">' + (i + 1) + '.</span>')
});
```

In the above code, we are using index that gets passed in the callback and adding one to it. No need of a separate counter.

Answer (score 1):

You are prepending a "const" string as `'<span class="lesson-number">' + 0 + '.</span> '` u must know that the prepend will only be called once in your code.

Here may be the solution

```
var outlineCount = 0
$('.page-template-page-outline .entry-content > h2').each(function(){
    $(this).prepend('<span class="lesson-number">' + outlineCount++ + '.</span> ');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument being passed to the prepend method is resolved one before the method is called; i.e.

```js
'<span class="lesson-number">' + outlineCount++ + '.</span> '
```

is resolved to:

```js
'<span class="lesson-number">0.</span> '
```

which is then prepend to every element matching the CSS selector `'.page-template-page-outline .entry-content > h2'`.

You would need to iterate over each element returned for your method to work, e.g.

```js
$('.page-template-page-outline .entry-content > h2').each(function ( index, element ) {
    element.prepend('<span class="lesson-number">' + ++outlineCount + '.</span> ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is may be off-topic, as it is not answering the problem you had (and andwered by the previous response), but you could use an `<ol>` element to get an automaticaly numbered list, with the help of [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) jquery functions to insert it in an existing page.

Yet, the best solution should be to change the html directly if you have the possibility:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <ol>
    <li><h2>Greetings</h2></li>
    <li><h2>Introductions</h2></li>
    <li><h2>Numbers</h2></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

```js
$('.page-template-page-outline .entry-content ').wrapInner('<ol></ol>');
$('.page-template-page-outline .entry-content > ol > h2 ').wrap('<li></li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-template-page-outline">
  <div class="entry-content">
    <h2>Greetings</h2>
    <h2>Introductions</h2>
    <h2>Numbers</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```